# How to modify CSS or JS file from "materialize:materialize" package in Meteor

Tags: javascript, css, meteor, materialize

Currently I am using the package `materialize:materialize` on my project. I wish to customize the style and modify the CSS and JS file in the package, however, I am not sure what is the best way to modify the files.

I found the CSS and JS files in `.meteor/local/build/programs/`, when I change the codes there, I can find the change in my site. But when I run the meteor again, it seems that the package load the files to the original version and new codes are changed back.

Thanks for helping me to get the solution. 
Best

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a folder under the folder `client/` or justwith a new `css` file, and start overwriting the classes of the materialize css.

something like `client/styles/mycustom.css`

mycustom.css

`.someclass {
   whatever: whatever
}`

you shouldn't modify anything inside of the package folder since you don't have complete control and might be overwrite by meteor.

Comment: `client` and `server` are special folders in meteor, if you dont have it you can create them.

Comment: Thanks, it works. I agree with you, this should be the proper way